# Apache Nifi - Submitting Spark batch jobs through Apache Livy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-nifi, livy

I want to schedule my spark batch jobs from Nifi. I can see there is [ExecuteSparkInteractive](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-livy-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.livy.ExecuteSparkInteractive/index.html) processor which submit spark jobs to Livy, but it executes the code provided in the property or from the content of the incoming flow file. How should I schedule my spark batch jobs from Nifi and also take different actions if the batch job fails or succeeds?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ExecuteProcess](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess/index.html) to run a spark-submit command. 
But what you seem to be looking for, is not a DataFlow management tool, but a workflow manager. Two great examples for workflow managers are: [Apache Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) & [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/).

If you still want to use it to schedule spark jobs, you can use the [GenerateFlowFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateFlowFile/index.html) processor to be scheduled(on primary node so it won't be scheduled twice - unless you want to), and then connect it to the ExecuteProcess processor, and make it run the `spark-submit` command.

For a little more complex workflow, I've written an [article](https://medium.com/@ben2460/chronically-execute-processes-in-nifi-5fec582c2de6) about :) 
Hope it will help.

Comment: Nice Article. I have already done that few months ago and my approach is similar to yours. I have written an custom processor to Join based on conditions.